# Personal training and fitness websites

Tags: personal-training

What are the best personal training websites? I am looking for site that will provide me with all of the information I would get from working with a personal trainer, such as exercise programs, nutrition recommendations, etc.

Comment: I strongly recommend you add some specifications for the answers, because in it's current shape it will only attract one-liner answers! So what kind of exercise are you looking for, what's the goal you want to achieve, should it have an app as well, what is so great about the webapp, do they actually use it or just found it through Google?

Comment: Personal trainer for: running, walking, weight-lifting? Maybe a personal skiing trainer? Your particular goals are very important in answering this question... _Hint: Add your goals to your question!_

Answer (score 0):

A good jumpstart would be to register at [this site](http://www.bodybuildingforum.ie/ucp.php?mode=register) and download the workout logs [here](http://www.musclehack.com/download-free-workout-logs-for-tht-volume-cycle/). This is all about THT Volume Cycle and HIT training — for maximizing strength and muscle growth. The workout logs have embedded links that show how to execute each exercise for each body part. It also tells you how many sets you should do, how many minutes you should rest, and how many weeks you should keep exercising before cycling from THT to HIT training.  You'll also be receiving additional "must-know" information/updates while training through email.

A few sample infos that I got are:

- [What To Do In Between Sets To Maximize Growth](http://www.musclehack.com/what-to-do-in-between-sets-to-maximize-growth/)
- [Massive Muscle Gains: Want 12lbs Of Muscle This Year?](http://www.musclehack.com/massive-muscle-gains-want-12lbs-of-muscle-this-year/)

A whole lot more will be sent to you from time to time.

Comment: This doesn't explain us what it does, why its any good and frankly not even the name of the site!

Answer (score 0):

There are many variations and skill levels of personal trainers.  Some are vanilla gym guides, showing the proper use of equipment and how to set up a standard workout routine.  Others are available for specific sports and/or goals and/or recovery.  I would recommend listing what it is you're trying to achieve, how much time you have available and how much money you're willing to spend, and then search local gyms or recommendations from friends and then search the web for local ones.

I've found that the best way to find one is through observing them train others (at your gym) and then picking the one who provides the type of interaction and results you want.  Personal training has a lot to do with good personality match and then skill level... it's not just direction but motivation that they provide.